# How to create an a alternating list for a given number of elements N?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create a list in python that goes like `[1, 1, -2, -2, 3, 3, -4, -4, ...]` for a given number of elements `N`?

For example, if `N = 5`, the list should return `[1, 1, -2, -2, 3]`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I couldn't get around the border case i.e. for odd N

Comment: Can you add your own attempt to the question then? We can help you with *that* instead of writing all the code for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
[(i // 2) + 1 if (i // 2) % 2 == 0 else -(i // 2) - 1 for i in range(N)]
```

This simply calculates each number in the series.

Demo:

```
>>> N = 5
>>> [(i // 2) + 1 if (i // 2) % 2 == 0 else -(i // 2) - 1 for i in range(N)]
[1, 1, -2, -2, 3]
>>> N = 10
>>> [(i // 2) + 1 if (i // 2) % 2 == 0 else -(i // 2) - 1 for i in range(N)]
[1, 1, -2, -2, 3, 3, -4, -4, 5, 5]
```